# Using nodejs to make Slack bot , Slack events not working

Tags: node.js, bots, slack-api, slack

I am using one Slack bot library,

[github.com/blocktrail/slack-tipbot](https://github.com/blocktrail/slack-tipbot/tree/master/lib)

and using this `nodejs` library ,

`var Slack = require('slack-client');`

There are 4 events that are working perfect:

```
slack.on('open', function(e) {});
slack.on('message', function(message) {});
slack.on('close', function(e) {});
slack.on('error', function(error) {});
```

but when i am trying another event after looking up at [slack events API list](https://api.slack.com/events-api)

and using event like this

```
 slack.on('member_joined_channel',function(ss){});
```

its not working

What can be the issue?

Comment: From reading the docs it seems that all events go through the `message` handler, so when a member joins you should receive a response in the `slack.on('message'...` section. Add a `console.log(message)` in that section and see if you get a response stating a member joined.

Comment: Also the nodejs library you're using is deprecated so has no documentation (that I can find). The following library seems to implement a similar thing so may help: https://www.npmjs.com/package/slackbots

Comment: @benShelton let me check it .

Comment: @benshelton i have checked it, it just prints the message that "@user" has joined the channel no other info. no event

Comment: @benshelton and the library you mentioned also supports these 4 events. Do you know any other way we can utilize other events as well

Comment: Without the documentation it's hard to say what is meant to happen. Either try with another library or check your Slack configuration (it seems you have to enable events in Slack first to receive them according to this: https://api.slack.com/events-api#subscriptions) Maybe someone else has experience with this specific library?

Answer (score 0):

A tad late to the party on this one. I just got done building a SlackBot with their Node SDK package and it was perfection. You get all of the API methods built into the SDK and it is all promise based with async/await. It makes it so much nicer to string together all the asynchronous logic.

https://slack.dev/node-slack-sdk/